# Is there a way to graph 3d points on a cylinder graph in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm in the process of graphing different color values based on their hue, lightness, and saturation as the xyz axis.  It works pretty well with matplotlib, here's a pic.

[image]

But recently I saw an image of a graph on the internet that's cylinder based

[image: cylinder graph]

I couldn't find any info on the internet about it, and it seems that matplotlib doesn't support making this kind of graph.  Does anyone know of a way to plot scatter points on a cylinder graph in python?

Answer (score 0):

In order to place points on the surface of a cylinder, you would have to parameterize the surface. This is one way:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def cylinder(R, z_min, z_max, theta_max, N):
    z = np.random.uniform(z_min, z_max, N)
    theta = np.random.uniform(0, theta_max, N)
    x = R * np.cos(theta)
    y = R * np.sin(theta)
    return x, y, z

def dics(z, R_max, theta_max, N):
    r = np.random.uniform(0, R_max, N)
    theta = np.random.uniform(0, theta_max, N)
    x = r * np.cos(theta)
    y = r * np.sin(theta)
    return x, y, z * np.ones_like(x)

def plane(theta, R_max, z_min, z_max, N):
    r = np.random.uniform(0, R_max, N)
    x = r * np.cos(theta)
    y = r * np.sin(theta)
    z = np.random.uniform(z_min, z_max, N)
    return x, y, z

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection="3d")

N = 1000
z_min = -1
z_max = 1
R = 3
theta_max = 1.5 * np.pi

# points on the cylindrical surface
x_cyl, y_cyl, z_cyl = cylinder(R, z_min, z_max, theta_max, N)
ax.scatter(x_cyl, y_cyl, z_cyl)

# points on the top cap
x_top, y_top, z_top = dics(z_max, R, theta_max, N)
ax.scatter(x_top, y_top, z_top)

# points on the bottom cap
x_bottom, y_bottom, z_bottom = dics(z_min, R, theta_max, N)
ax.scatter(x_bottom, y_bottom, z_bottom)

# points on the first slice-wall
x1, y1, z1 = plane(0, R, z_min, z_max, N)
ax.scatter(x1, y1, z1)

# points on the second slice-wall
x2, y2, z2 = plane(theta_max, R, z_min, z_max, N)
ax.scatter(x2, y2, z2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Then, you would have to modify the above functions to return the angle `theta` and the radius `r`, so that you can apply colors based on H, S, V, but that's left for you as an exercise :)

Edit: if you just want to plot scatter points into the volume of a sliced cylinder, you could modify the `cylinder` function in this way:

```py
def cylinder(R, z_min, z_max, theta_max, N):
    z = np.random.uniform(z_min, z_max, N)
    theta = np.random.uniform(0, theta_max, N)
    r = np.random.uniform(0, R, N)
    x = r * np.cos(theta)
    y = r * np.sin(theta)
    return x, y, z
```